# Safety in using different software installation methods (simultaneously)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I wonder if installing software from outside the Ubuntu packaging system may confuse apt/dpkg tools. I know that installing too new .deb packages and trying to recursively solve dependencies by hand (because dependendencies are also too new) may confuse them. But what about different packaging tools like pip or snap? And what about installing things by "sudo make install" from source.
I think apt/dpkg is not aware of all of this software being installed. Is it then safe to the integrity of this packaging system? What if I do for example:
`sudo apt install cmake #low version from Ubuntu repository`
 
`sudo make install #high version from Cmake website in sources`
`sudo apt remove cmake` 
I suppose that both installations aim into the same location in filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to assume that `dpkg` and `apt` are unaware of this extra software from `pip` or `sudo make install`. However, both installations *do not* aim into the same location in filesystem. Extra software from `pip` or `sudo make install` is installed in directories that have a higher priority (are earlier) in your `$PATH`.

If you install packages from `pip` with the `--user` flag, without `sudo`, the packages will install to `~/.local/bin`. Packages installed with `sudo make install` will usually install to `/usr/local/bin`.

If you run: `echo $PATH` you will see that these paths are listed before the standard directories that `deb` packages use so the manually installed packages are executed when you run a command. This helps to avoid conflict if the same package was also installed using `apt` or `dpkg`.

Therefore, you can keep your `apt` dependencies satisfied and you do not need to uninstall the `apt` version of `cmake`. This way, you can still call on the `dpkg` installed version of `cmake` in a script or the terminal by executing the full path: `/usr/bin/cmake`  Run the command: `cmake` to execute the `sudo make install` version.

The same goes for packages installed using `pip`. For example, if you installed `youtube-dl` through `apt-get` and then installed using: `pip install youtube-dl --user`, the `pip` version: `~/.local/bin/youtube-dl` would execute instead of `/usr/bin/youtube-dl`.

You can have two conflicting versions installed and still use them both.

That is not to say that there will not be conflicts. Your system depends on certain packages like Python that may not run correctly if you change the system default version. Additionally, installing randomly downloaded software is considered less safe if you do not trust your sources. Manually downloaded software may also have bugs or security flaws and you must remember to manually update by downloading the software or using `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Can then I make apt/dpkg to install into /usr/local (or ~/.local) if I don't quite believe certain package? I suppose that not, because .deb packages contain stiff locations.
On the other hand it isn't a big problem to add one infix while processing by these tools.

Comment: I mean that then it would not be necessary to remove another package that may be lower (and safer) version